# angular 2 - how to configure route guard to only allow routes from certain url?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a way to let route guard to only allow routes from certain url? For example, I want '/url2' to be only accessed from /'url1' not from any other urls or by entering 'example.com/url2' directly to the address bar.

The only solution I can think of is to use service to share status, but I'm trying to make it possible in the route guard since I think it's doable if the source url can be accessed inside route guard. The only problem I'm facing is that I have no idea on where to find source url from the route guard.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can access the current Router path in the guard by injecting `Router` in the constructor of the `CanActivate` guard and using `router.url`:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        this.router.url  //<-- should be current path, whereas the route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot object should be the requested route
        ...
    }
```

Do whatever checks and then return a `boolean` or `Observable<boolean>` from the `canActivate` method.